# c# Calculate time remaining until certain time

Tags: c#, timespan

So I am trying to find the time that is closest to happening from a list of three times. Then I am trying to calculate the time remaining until the closest time happens. My code to find the closest time works but my timeleft code only works when the chosen closest time is either 2pm, or 10pm. The three times I am checking to see what are closest is 6am, 2pm, or 10pm. But if it is after 10pm instead of saying 8 hours til 6 am it will say -16hours. If anyone can help would be greatly appreciated!

Sample Input: 11pm
Expect output: 7 (11 pm would mean it is 7 hours until 6 am)

Here is my time left code:

```
public static TimeSpan timeLeft(TimeSpan ts)
{
    TimeSpan time = new TimeSpan(0);

    DateTime next = DateTime.Now;
    next = next.AddMinutes(-next.Minute).AddSeconds(-next.Second) + ts;
    if (next < DateTime.Now)
        next = next.AddHours(1);
         
    return next - DateTime.Now;
}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your post with sample inputs (both `ts` and `DateTime.Now`), expected output, and actual output?

Comment: My bad im having trouble editing it but, my sample input would be ts containing 7, 16, and 23. The expected output would be 5, 6, 7. Actual output would be, 5, 6, -17

Comment: " ts containing 7, 16, and 23." , TS doesnt contain anything like that. So that comment doesnt clarify anything.

Comment: From the description I expected to see the input being a DateTime object "My code to find the closest time works", ie I expected to see `DateTime closest` as an argument. PLease clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: @dillionn - Here's a fiddle with a simplified and testable version of your code. https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ut2NtL Can you please put in actual inputs that demonstrate your issue and then post it in your question?