# C# Calculate how long it will be until specified timespan

Tags: c#, timespan

So I am trying to calculate how long it will be until a specific time. ButI cant seem to get it working.

An example is say im trying to calculate how long it will be from now to 06:00:00am So say it is 10:30pm I want to see how long it will be until til 6am the next day. So the correct answer would be 7 hours and 30 mins. Or another example say it is 8:30pm I want to see how long it will be until 10pm. If anyone could provide me with some code to help it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# Calculate time remaining until certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71551200/c-sharp-calculate-time-remaining-until-certain-time) You just posted this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare the timespan first then add one day if needed.

```cs
        static TimeSpan TimeDiff(TimeSpan nowSpan, TimeSpan ts)
        {
            if (nowSpan > ts)
            {
                ts = ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
            }
            return ts - nowSpan;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(TimeDiff(new TimeSpan(22, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0)));
            //  07:30:00
            Console.WriteLine(TimeDiff(new TimeSpan(20, 30, 0), new TimeSpan(22, 0, 0)));
            //  01:30:00
            // You may want use DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay as the first parameter
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DateTime later = DateTime.Now.AddHours(3);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(later.Subtract(now).TotalSeconds);
```